# Does Guice binding bind subclass as well?

Tags: guice

So I have a module which binds an Interface with an implementation class.

```
bind(ILocalStore.class).to(LocalStore.class);
```

Will this binding also inject the following constructor:

```
@Inject
public LocalStoreUser(LocalStore localstore) {
    this.localstore = localstore
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The injection will work, but not because of the binding.

Guice treats lookups as if they were a simple `Map<Key, Provider>` lookup, where Key is composed of a (binding annotation, parameterized type) pair. Guice will not automatically walk up the type hierarchy for you, or otherwise modify the lookup key (checking for a non-annotated or raw type binding, for instance).

However, if LocalStore has a public no-argument constructor (or an `@Inject`-annotated constructor as you've listed), Guice can create the type directly, so the code above will work—it just has nothing to do with binding subclasses automatically.

---

Consider the following example:

```
interface A {}
interface B extends A {}
public class C implements B {}
```

- Without any bindings at all, you could inject C, because it has an implicit public no-arg constructor. The same would apply if C has an `@Inject`-annotated constructor. Requesting injection of A or B will fail.
- If you were to `bind(A.class).to(C.class)` you could inject A (explicit) or C (implicit) but not B. **Guice will not bind the subinterface as well, so B has no implementation.**
- Same goes for superclasses/superinterfaces: If you were to `bind(B.class).to(C.class)` you could inject B (explicit) or C (implicit) but not A, even though B extends A.
- If you were to `bind(A.class).to(B.class)` *and* `bind(B.class).to(C.class)`, then you could inject A, B, or C without repeating yourself.