# Guice - How to bind all subclasses of a class to a common subclass?

Tags: guice

I want to bind all UseCaseFactory subclasses to UseCaseFactories (that is a subclass all of them).

[image]

Instead of listing all the subclasses (this works):

```
bind(DeleteEmployeeUseCaseFactory.class).toInstance(useCaseFactories);
bind(GetEmployeeUseCaseFactory.class).toInstance(useCaseFactories);
```

I want to do something like this. How can I ?

```
bind(subClassesOf(UseCaseFactory.class)).toInstance(useCaseFactories);
```

Comment: I don't believe there's a built-in way to do this, particularly given that you probably don't want to bind Object to your instance even if your UseCaseFactoriesImpl necessarily extends Object. You may have to write your own reflective equivalent with the filtering you need.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is multi bindings: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings

Comment: Multibindings are useful for binding multiple instances to a particular interface. This question is asking the opposite.

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598703/does-guice-binding-bind-subclass-as-well